# Why are append and uncons for catenable lists merely amortized O(1)?

Tags: data-structures, sml, ml, purely-functional

I took Okasaki's implementation of catenable lists, and refactored it a little bit to avoid Boolean blindness issues. Other than that, the data structure itself remains unchanged:

```
functor CatList (Q : QUEUE) :> CAT_LIST =
struct
  (* private stuff, not exposed by CAT_LIST *)

  structure L = Lazy
  structure O = Option  (* from basis library *)

  datatype 'a cons = ::: of 'a * 'a cons L.lazy Q.queue

  infixr 5 :::

  (* Q.snoc : 'a Q.queue * 'a -> 'a Q.queue *)
  fun link (x ::: xs, ys) = x ::: Q.snoc (xs, ys)

  (* L.delay : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b L.lazy)
   * L.force : 'a L.lazy -> 'a
   * Q.uncons : 'a Q.queue -> ('a * 'a Q.queue lazy) option *)
  fun linkAll (xs, ys) =
    let
      val xs = L.force xs
      val ys = L.force ys
    in
      case Q.uncons ys of
          NONE => xs
        | SOME ys => link (xs, L.delay linkAll ys)
    end

  (* public stuff, exposed by CAT_LIST *)

  type 'a list = 'a cons option

  val empty = NONE

  (* L.pure : 'a -> 'a L.lazy *)
  fun append (xs, NONE) = xs
    | append (NONE, xs) = xs
    | append (SOME xs, SOME ys) = SOME (link (xs, L.pure ys))

  (* Q.empty : 'a Q.queue *)
  fun cons (x, xs) = append (SOME (x ::: Q.empty), xs)
  fun snoc (xs, x) = append (xs, SOME (x ::: Q.empty))

  (* O.map : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a option -> 'b option) *)
  fun uncons NONE = NONE
    | uncons (SOME (x ::: xs)) = SOME (x, L.delay (O.map linkAll) (Q.uncons xs))
end
```

In his book, Okasaki claims that, given an implementation of queues with `O(1)` operations (either worst-case or amortized), `append` and `uncons` are amortized `O(1)`.

Why can't his claim be strengthened? Given an implementation of real-time queues (all operations are worst-case `O(1)`), `append` and `uncons` look worst-case `O(1)` to me. All recursive calls in `linkAll` are guarded by `L.delay`, and none of the public operations ever forces more than one suspension. Is my reasoning (or my code) wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question on catenable lists. You need to also take into account that forcing a suspension may result in a cascade of forces. Note that *linkAll* forces its input list, which could be a yet unevaluated suspension 's'. Forcing 's' may in turn force another suspension and so on. 
This would indeed happen if you do a sequence of *uncons* operations on the list. Eventually, at most after 'n' uncons operations, the data structure may degenerate to the naive *Cons* list (Cons(x, Cons(y, ...))), where 'n' is the size of the list. Any further *uncons* operations will have constant time.
Therefore the data structure does have an amortized constant time bound, but it is not worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable (purely functional) queues have only amortized O(1) constructors and destructors.

http://www.westpoint.edu/eecs/SiteAssets/SitePages/Faculty%20Publication%20Documents/Okasaki/jfp95queue.pdf

Comment: The abstract from the link you posted says: "We present purely functional implementations of queues and double-ended queues (deques) requiring only O(1) time per operation *in the worst case*." [emphasis mine]

Comment: And, if you consider laziness an effect (because a lazy thunk mutates internally), Hood-Melville queues are another example of queues whose operations are all worst-case O(1), and they do not even require internal mutation.

Comment: In addition to the (rather complicated) Hood-Melville queue, the much simpler scheduled banker's queue (as described by Okasaki) is a real-time structure.